# Ajax call firing in my knockout Click handler before click occurs

Tags: knockout.js

```
// partial view
<%
    '// serialising server model
    Dim serialisedModel As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)
%>


<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.min.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout.mapping.debug.js") %>">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/SearchingViewModel.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = <% Response.Write(serialisedModel) %>;
    $(document).ready(function() { ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data)); });
</script>


// rest of html page   




// SearchingViewModel.js

    function ViewModel(data) {
        var self = this;

        /// lot of observable properties here but left out for brevity

        /// Search viewModel
        self.search = new Search(data);

    } // end ViewModel


    function Search(data) {
        var self = this;

        /// initiates a search
        self.SearchData = function () { 
           $.ajax({
                url: '/pathToGetSearchResults',
                type: 'GET',
                // etc, etc, etc,
            };
        }
    }


    // HTML bit

    <input data-bind="click: search.SearchData" type="button" id="search-button" class="button" value="Search" />
```

I'm getting the server model, serialising it and passing it to the view model, which is in SearchingViewModel.js script.

The problem is that the ajax call fires when the page loads.
It will fire when the button is clicked per the binding but 
shouldn't it fire only when the click event is raised ?

How do I stop the unwanted behaviour ?

Comment: can you show us more code around how you are invoking ko's applybinding method?

Comment: I edited the post to show this.

Answer (score 4):

In my times working with Knockout, I've noticed this behavior of functions firing on page load when I put them in the click binding when 1. the variable you use in the binding is the actual function and 2. when you don't wrap the variable inside of a "function() { variable() }".

So I imagine in your HTML, it looks like this:

```
<button data-bind="click: functionToRun">
```

What you want is this:

```
<button data-bind="click: function() { functionToRun() }">
```

Edit: Ah, I didn't see you posted your HTML code. That is exactly what's going on. In your button data-bind, just change `data-bind="click: search.SearchData"` to be `data-bind="click: function() { search.SearchData() }"`. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[**Here is example and it works as well**](http://jsfiddle.net/88kcu/2/):

```
function ViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;

    /// lot of observable properties here but left out for brevity

    /// Search viewModel
    self.search = new Search(data);

} // end ViewModel


function Search(data) {
    var self = this;

    /// initiates a search
    self.SearchData = function () { 
      console.log('handler fired');
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel('test data'));
```

Comment: i see this works correctly here, but it doesn't work in my code base.  i ended up taking it out of knockoutjs (unfortunate, because it just isn't working out as had hoped) and returning to jQuery, which seems to have far more control.

Comment: @zebula dont give up on Knockout it's the best thing since sliced bread

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I would of gone this root.

```
    var  ViewModel = function() {
        var self = this;

        self.Search = function() {
        /// do a search
        ///Ajax stuff
        console.log('handler fired');

        }

        self.Init = function () {
        //jquery stuff if needed

        }  
    }


    $(document).ready(function () {

        var view = new ViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(view);
        view.Init();
    });


<input data-bind="click:  Search" type="button" id="search-button" class="button"   />
```